# Best runtime for n-1 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If an algorithm must make n-1 comparisons to **find a certain element**, then can we assume that best possible runtime of the algorithm is O(n)?
I know that the lower bound for sorting algorithms is nlogn but since we only return the found one element, I figured it would be possible to do better in terms of run time?
Thanks!

Comment: It has to do `n` comparisons unless there is a guarantee that the element exists that you can take into account when implementing the algorithm. Linear search has O(n) profile, yes.

Comment: The assumptions are that the array is unsorted with distinct elements. The goal is not to sort it, just to return a certain specified element. Linear sort would then be the fastest with O(n) I assume but, just for my understanding of how algorithms work, a recursive algorithm to perform the same task would be O(n) or O(nlogn)?

Comment: How would you do a recursive task any better than just linear search, if the collection is unsorted? You would gain no knowledge from comparing any element to the goal, except that that was not the right element. If you want a recursive algorithm that performs better than linear search, you also need to be able to gain some knowledge, and that would imply not necessarily that the array is sorted, but at least that there is a system to how the elements are organized that you can exploit.

Comment: In general, if the search is a one-off thing on an unsorted array, O(n) is probably your best bet. But if the array doesn't change, and you want to do multiple searches in it, you should probably sort first and then do a binary search. There is a tradeoff, so even two linear searches might not be enough to warrant the sort.

Answer (score 1):

To find a certain element in an unsorted list you need O(n).

But if you sort the array (takes O(n log n) in general) you can find a certain element in O(log n).

So if you want to find often elements in the same list it is most likely worth to sort the list to then be able to find elements much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is unsorted and you find some element in it then in worst case **Linear search algorithm** make n-1 comparisons and time complexity will be O(n).

But if you want to reduce your time complexity then first sort your array and use **Binary search algorithm** it is take **O(logn)** in worst case.

So **Binary search algorithm** is more efficient then linear search.

Answer (score 0):

For unsorted elements, worst case is when you have to go over all the elements, i.e., O(N). If you need many look-ups then you have several pre-processing alternatives that speed up all future accesses.

**Option 1:** put the elements in a standard hash table. Creating the hash table costs O(N), on average, and later pay O(1) on average for each lookup. This assumes that a reasonable hash-function can be created for this type of elements.

Most languages/libraries implement bucket-based hash-tables, which in pathological cases can put all elements in one bucket, costing O(N) per lookup.

**Option 2:** there are other hash-table implementations that don't suffer from pathological O(N) cases. The [Robin Hood hashing (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Robin_Hood_hashing) (more at [Programming.Guide](https://programming.guide/robin-hood-hashing.html)) guarantees O(log N) lookup in the worst case, with average of O(1).

**Option 3:** another option is to sort elements in O(N log N) once, and then use binary-search to lookup in O(log N). Usually this is slower than Robin Hood hashing (*Option 2*).

**Option 4:** If the values are simple integers with limited range, with max-min around N, then it is possible to put the values in an array (list), such that  `array[value-min]` will contain a count of how many times the value appears in the input. It costs O(N) to construct, and O(1) to lookup. Better, the constants for both preprocessing and lookup are significantly lower than in any other method.

**Note**: I didn't mention the O(N) [counting-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) as an alternative to the general case of O(N log N) sorting (*option 3*), since if `max(value)-min(value)` is small enough for counting-sort, then *option 4* is relevant and is simpler and faster.

If applicable, choose option 4, otherwise if you wish to invest time and code then choose option 2. If 4 isn't applicable, and 2 is not worth the effort in your case, then choose option 2 if you don't mind the pathological worst-case (never choose option 2 when an adversary may want to harm you in a DOS attack).

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with sorting, let alone linear search.

If you claim that `n-1` comparisons are mandated, then your problem has certainly complexity `Ω(n)`. But with that information alone, you can't guarantee `O(n)` because it is not said that these `n-1` comparisons are *sufficient*, nor that the algorithm does not perform extra operations, for instance to decide which comparisons to perform. It could turn out that your algorithm is `O(n³)` with no chance to do better, but we can't tell.

Best case complexity: `Ω(n)`.
Worst case complexity: unknown.

Comment: I am surprised to see many answerers jumping on the complexity of sorting/linear searching, when it is never said that these are relevant. All we know is "at least `n-1` comparisons" and nothing else is said about the problem.